# Syntax colouring when using Symbolize

Tags: syntax, custom-notation, syntax-highlighting

I need to use symbols with suffixes in order to make my code readable in relation to the Eurocodes. To do this I use [`Symbolize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/ref/Symbolize.html) from the [`` Notation` `` package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html), but have noticed that the syntax colouring does not work on symbols created in this way. This makes checking the code more difficult. Is there a way of getting the syntax colouring to work or am I doing something wrong?

Here is a toy example which seems to work if you copy and paste and then change it to Standard Form (<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>). Note the W is shown black  whereas the subscript is shown in blue. All the other symbols are shown blue even after they are defined.

```
Symbolize[
ParsedBoxWrapper[
SubscriptBox["γ", "M0"]]];
Symbolize[
ParsedBoxWrapper[
SubscriptBox["M", 
RowBox[{"c", ".", "y", ".", "Rd"}]]]]; Symbolize[
ParsedBoxWrapper[
SubscriptBox["W", 
RowBox[{"el", ".", "y"}]]]];

Subscript[M, c.y.Rd] = 50;
Subscript[W, el.y] = 0.05;
Subscript[γ, M0] = 1.2;

σ = Subscript[M, c.y.Rd]/(Subscript[W, 
 el.y]/Subscript[γ, M0])
```

1199.9999999999998

[image: Here is an image of what I mean]

Comment: Can you please give a small toy example which someone can copy, paste and try?

Comment: Here is a toy example.

Comment: Where? I cannot see that you edited your question or something like that.

Comment: My apologies halirutan I wanted to paste in code but it closed the comment when I hit the return key. I have now done so in the question

Comment: To update your question is the right way! You code can not be evaluated. Please [look at this answer](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6/187) to read how to post code here.

Comment: Thank you halirutan for the Link. Hopefully it will now work.

Comment: When you say suffixes, do you actually mean subscripts ($\text{name}_{\text{subscript}}$)?

Comment: Yes Szabolcs, I do. Sorry, I should be more precise.

Comment: I encountered the same issue. Did you find any solution? :)