# Syntax highlighting for Symbolized variables in Solve

Tags: front-end, symbols, syntax-highlighting

This is a duplicate of [Syntax colouring when using Symbolize](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16311/syntax-colouring-when-using-symbolize), but that post is almost eight years old and hasn't been active in almost four years.

Is it possible to get normal syntax highlighting for variable names made with `` Notation`Symbolize ``? E.g.

```
<< Notation`
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]];

Subscript[a, h] = 2
Solve[{
  b == Subscript[a, h],
  Subscript[b, k] == b}, {b, Subscript[b, k]}]
```

Produces the following, where subscripted variables have been highlighted either wrongly or not at all:

[image: Syntax coloring example]

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is (still) nothing you can do about the highlighting